# Error on printing a character value from a string

Tags: c

The user has to enter some items and then the matrix has to print them on 3x4
When i use the "%c" instead of "%s" works but it only shows a character but when I want to print the whole word with "%s" wont work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char objetos[10][10];

int main(){

    int i,e;

    for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
        for (e=1;e<=4;e++){
            system("cls");  
            printf("Ingrese El Objeto Personal %i-%i: ",i,e);
            scanf("%s",&objetos[i][e]);
        }
    }

    system("cls");
    for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
        for (e=1;e<=4;e++){ 
            printf("%s",objetos[i][e]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a matrix of characters. You need a matrix of strings.

Comment: Why do your loops start from `1`? Array indexes start at `0`.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I want to print the whole word with "%s" wont work ?

The format specifier `%s` expects argument of `const char*` and `objetos[i][e]` is not of `char*` type, its of `char` type. 
Change this

```
for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
   for (e=1;e<=4;e++){ 
   printf("%s",objetos[i][e]);
}
```

to

```
for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
    printf("%s",objetos[i]);
}
```

Also while scanning, this

```
scanf("%s",&objetos[i][e]);
```

is not correct, use `%c` instead of `%s` here.

For e.g

```
for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
     for (e=1;e<=4;e++){
         system("cls");  
         printf("Ingrese El Objeto Personal %i-%i: ",i,e);
         scanf(" %c",&objetos[i][e]);
     }
}
```

Side note, array index starts from `zero(0)` not `one(1)` in `C`. You may seems to put data into `objetos[1]` & read from `objetos[1]` but mistakenly if your program ever try read from `objetos[0]` then it create the issue.

Better start rotating loop from `0th` index. For e.g

```
for (i=0;i<=3;i++){
    for (e=0;e<=4;e++){
      scanf(" %c",&objetos[i][e]); /* give the whitespace before %c to avoid buffer overrun */
     }
}
```

Comment: So it is not possible to use a string character inside the matrix? I'm sorry if I'm asking stupid questions. Im new in programming.

Comment: Your matrix is a matrix of single characters. You can't store a multiple character string inside a single `char`.